# What does Mega-Word (MW) mean?

Tags: memory-management, cpu, computer-science, cpu-architecture

I have a question about data sizes, I came across a question about what is the size of a physical address if the size of the physical memory is 1MW (Mega-Word).
I have never heard about this term (Mega-Word) and I didn't find much on the net.

I hope you can explain me briefly what Mega-Word is.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know what the individual terms "mega" and "word" mean?

Comment: I haven't heard that term before, but if it means anything other than 1 million (or most likely 2^20) words, it is badly named.

Answer (score 3):

Some systems do not use bytes at all. There was a time not long ago when it was common for systems to use memory organized into 12 and 36-bit "words." Both Sperry (CTS) and DEC (TOPS) had 36-bit systems, for example.

On such systems, there was no such thing as a "megabyte." Instead, memory was measured in megawords where a word was 36-bits.